# Can't get data from json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I need to get brand: "hello world" 
When I send using post data with json and get it with

```
 $input = Input::all();
```

then with

```
die(print_r($input));
```

this is written

```
Array ([[], {brand: "hello world"}, [], 1427154586016])1
```

And

I tryed using json_encode and get with

```
die(print_r($encode));
```

this

```
{data: "{"brand":"Hello world"}", dc: "142715"}1
```

now if I do

$brand = $encode['data'] or $brand = $encode['brand']

I get an error.
How do I get Hello world to var $brand

Comment: data you are sending is not in valid json format. you can validate any json here. http://jsonlint.org/

Comment: First,Larvel got `dd` function witch is much more useful then just die and print. To get the brand input you could do `Input::get('brand')` if thats the name of your input

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using **json_encode()** when you should be using **json_decode()**. But like kamlesh pointed out, it appears that your original JSON data is not valid JSON to begin with, so this would not help you. [This wiki article has an example of valid syntax.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Also, if you're using laravel, you can use the helper function **dd()**, which will **die()** and **var_dump()** automatically for you, saving you a bit of time.

Hopefully this solves your problem, but if not, [read the docs for the Input](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input). There should be something there to get you on the right track.